# Does anyone use SharePoint to manage mini-projects?

Tags: 2010, solution

Does anyone use SharePoint to manage mini-projects? If so, how? Any custom lists/workflows that you find helpful?

I know SharePoint has an OTP Project Tasks list but it's very basic.

I was thinking of creating a solution that uses the Project Tasks list but adds a lot more. Something where:

- a master list to list all the projects
- a Project Tasks list to list associated tasks for a project
- workflows to trigger reminder e-mails for unfinished tasks

  - it could be set up so a week/month before a task is due the reminder e-mail is sent weekly/monthly but when the task is due in a week/month then the reminder e-mail is sent daily/weekly
- different views to show tasks by project or task owner so people can see all their unfinished tasks
- additional features???

Comment: Have you tried Project Site Template? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-started-with-a-project-site-8b68274b-622d-4a99-9245-1d205897cd43?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: The project site template is 2013. In 2010, you can use a Microsoft Project site if you're connected to a project server. But I'm not a fan of how it looks visually and, as far as I know, it doesn't offer an out-of-the-box way to display an overview of all of the projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have an entire e-Project Management Office set up this way. It's a site collection with subsites by division, then we use a custom site template to create a subsite for each project, then roll up an overview of each project to the home page. In each project, we use tasks, milestone, project document library for project charter, requirements documents, etc. We have alerts set on tasks. You could create a "My Active Tasks" view that would allow the logged in user to see what they still have to do. We have a third party tool to send alerts weekly for unfinished tasks, or you could do this with a custom timer job.

There are a couple ways to build a simpler version. Each project could be a summary task, with child tasks indicating tasks for that project. You could write workflows on the task to send an email on the due date if the status isn't marked complete or the progress isn't set to 100%. You could also show the task list as a calendar with a view for each project.

Comment: Or you could have a master project list, and add a lookup field to the task list to choose which project the task is associated to. Then you could group tasks by project, create views for each project, or set up a web part page with a filter web part to filter by project.